# Single Linked List not working (C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list

The following code builds correctly but causes the program to crash when I run it. Can someone please tell me whats wrong with it. I suspect that there is something wrong with the DeleteNode function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class list {
private:
    typedef struct node {
        int data;
        node* next;
    }* nodePtr;  //this means that 'nodePtr' will mean a pointer to the struct node

nodePtr head;
nodePtr current;
nodePtr temp;

public:
list() {  //constuctor
    head = NULL;
    current = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
};

void AddNode(int addData)  //to add a particular data value
{
    nodePtr n= new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = addData;

    if (head != NULL) {  //if a list is already set up
        current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {  //to get to the last node in the list
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = n;
    }
    else {  // if list is not created
        head = n;  //new node is front of the list
    }
}

void DeleteNode(int delData)  //to delete a particular data value
{
    nodePtr delPtr = NULL;
    temp = head;
    current = head;

    while (current != NULL  && current->data!=delData) {  //pass through whole list && find value
        temp = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (current = NULL) {  //data value not found in list
        cout << delData << " was not in the list." << endl;
        delete delPtr;  //to free up memory space
    }
    else {
        delPtr = current;
        current = current->next;
        temp->next = current;  //to reconnect list

        if (delPtr == head) {
            head = head->next;
            temp = head;
        }

        delete delPtr;
        cout << "The value " << delData << "was deleted." << endl;
    }
}

void PrintList()  //to print all the data values
{
    current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {  //to go through the data valued of the list
        cout << current->data << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}

};



int main()
{
    list Shahzad;

    Shahzad.AddNode(2);
    Shahzad.AddNode(78);
    Shahzad.AddNode(28);
    Shahzad.AddNode(2398);

    Shahzad.DeleteNode(78);
    Shahzad.PrintList();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I didn't read it all, but `if (current = NULL)` that can't be good

Comment: Also, just use `std::forward_list` instead of re-rolling your own. If this is an assignment to do it yourself, you could at least make it easier on yourself by using `std::unique_ptr` to manage memory and not have to worry about delete mishaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is with the following line:

```
if (current = NULL)
```

You're actually *assigning* `null` to `current` at this point.

This should actually be:

```
if (current == NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, few code and file management remarks: consider separating your code into `.h` file where class members are declared and `.cpp` where class members are implemented, this will make your class easy to comprehend and possible errors will be easier to locate.

Secondly, a general advice when dealing with structures containing pointers is attention to proper resource management, i.e. pointer definitions, initialisations and deletions should be dealt with caution. If you are novice, consider the use of already provided *smart pointer* facilities like: [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) which will *"retain sole ownership of an object through a pointer and destroys that object when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope"*

Thirdly, use debugger to get rid of trivial errors like:

```
if (current = NULL)
```

which by the way contains additional inaccuracy expressed in the use of `NULL` instead of the pointer literal `nullptr`.

Lastly, check each of the member functions separately after you finish the initial implementation and only then proceed with further class expansion, otherwise you risk the accumulation of errors from multiple sources which will make your job very difficult

---

Answer (score 0):

In your delete function in the case of which the node isn't found, you are deleting delPtr.

However, delPtr was never instantiated or assigned so you are trying to delete something that doesn't exist.

Always enclose pointer deletions in if statements to avoid this issue. Try this:

```
if (delPtr) delete delPtr;
```

Comment: That certainly doesn't causes a  problem, who taught you so? `if (delPtr) delete delPtr;` is redundant. `delete` works transparently with `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the suggestions here, you can use some safe programming practices to catch bugs early.

For ex: you wrote

```
if (current = NULL)
```

Instead, try writing the value being checked on the LHS and the variable on the RHS like this:

```
if ( NULL == current)
```

Here, if you mistyped

```
if (NULL = current)
```

the compiler will complain. You have a compile time bug now instead of a run-time one. This is far easier to find and debug.